# get Insert id for meta field

Tags: post-meta, meta-query, user-meta

I'm in a situation where i also need to get the id of the inserted meta( `meta_id` for post meta and `umeta_id` for user meta)

For eg i add a user meta

```
add_user_meta($user_id,'some_key',$some_value,false);
```

is there a built in method of getting the umeta_id for this meta field without using custom query?

Same case for  retrieving meta value with meta id. I had to use this

```
$sql_query = 'select umeta_id as my_key_id, meta_value from  wp_usermeta where user_id = "'.$user_id.'" and meta_key = "some_key" order by my_key_id asc';
```

Any better alternative?

Answer (score 1):

No need to get Insert id for meta field.You get key value by using this function.

```
$user_some_value = get_user_meta( $user_id, some_key );
```

Comment: I'm aware this is how we obtain value BUT sorry this is NOT what i need

Comment: ok.You can get last insert id $lastid = $wpdb->insert_id;

Answer (score 0):

`$wpdb->insert_id` was the simple solution.

Example:

```
global $wpdb;
add_user_meta($user_id,'some_key',$some_value,false);
$new_meta_key_id = $wpdb->insert_id;
```

Comment: Can you show us a better example of the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything special here [since 3.3](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/18445/trunk/wp-includes/meta.php), because `add_user_meta()` [returns the meta ID](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_user_meta/):

```
$meta_id = add_user_meta( $user_id, 'some_key', $some_value, false );
```